# Is there a way to set data in a module to reuse it in module methods in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, oop

I have a Report class defined as follows:

```
class Report

include Parser

 def initialize(file: file)
  @file = remove_bookmarks(file: parse(file)) 
  @proofread_text = original(file: @file)
  @original_text = proofread(file: @file)
  @paragraphs = paragraphs(file: @file)
end


end
```

The Parser module is as follows:

```
module Parser

    def parse(file:file)
      zip_file = Zip::File.open(file) 
    end

    def remove_bookmarks(file: file)
      file.at("//w:bookmarkStart").remove if file.at("//w:bookmarkStart")
      file.at("//w:bookmarkEnd").remove if file.at("//w:bookmarkEnd")
    end

    def proofread(file: file)
       text(@file, filter: 'del')
    end

    def original(file: file)
      text(@file)
    end

    def paragraphs(file: file)
     file.xpath('//w:p[w:ins or w:del]')
    end 

    def text(file: file, filter: 'ins')
      xpath("//text()[not(ancestor::w:#{filter})]").map(&:text).join("")
    end

end
```

I noticed that my initialize method passes the same file to different methods in the Parser module.

Is there a way to set the file data in Module to be able to use it within the module so that I don't have to pass the file object every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `@file` instance variable in methods of `Parser` module as when you includes a module in a class, methods of modules act as instance methods of the class.

You can use `@file` as shown below.

```
class Report

include Parser

  def initialize(file: file)
    @file = remove_bookmarks(file: parse(file)) 
    @proofread_text = original
    @original_text = proofread
    @paragraphs = paragraphs
  end
end

module Parser
  def parse(file:file)
    zip_file = Zip::File.open(file) 
  end

  def remove_bookmarks(file: file)
    file.at("//w:bookmarkStart").remove if file.at("//w:bookmarkStart")
    file.at("//w:bookmarkEnd").remove if file.at("//w:bookmarkEnd")
  end

  def proofread
    text(@file, filter: 'del')
  end

  def original
    text(@file)
  end

  def paragraphs
    @file.xpath('//w:p[w:ins or w:del]')
  end 

  def text(file: file, filter: 'ins')
    xpath("//text()[not(ancestor::w:#{filter})]").map(&:text).join("")
  end
end
```

Only thing you have to careful about is If the `Parser` module is included in any other class, you have create `@file` variable before using any method of parser module.

Answer (score 1):

If you define `attr_reader :file` in your `Report` class, you can call file from your `Parser` module. However, be careful with naming of the arguments. I would suggest using `zip_file`.

```
class Report
  include Parser

  attr_reader :file

  def initialize(zip_file)
    @file = remove_bookmarks(zip_file) 
    @proofread_text = original
    @original_text = proofread
    @paragraphs = paragraphs
  end
end

module Parser
  def remove_bookmarks(zip_file)
    parse(zip_file)
    zip_file.tap do |z|
      z.at("//w:bookmarkStart").remove if file.at("//w:bookmarkStart")
      z.at("//w:bookmarkEnd").remove if file.at("//w:bookmarkEnd")
    end
  end

  def proofread
    text('del')
  end

  def original
    text
  end

  def paragraphs
    file.xpath('//w:p[w:ins or w:del]')
  end 

  private

  def text(filter = 'ins')
    file.xpath("//text()[not(ancestor::w:#{filter})]").map(&:text).join("")
  end

  def parse(zip_file)
    Zip::File.open(zip_file) 
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

You should just be able to use instance variables. You've even done that in a few places already.

```
class Report

  include Parser

   def initialize(file: file)
     parse_file
     remove_bookmarks
     @proofread_text = original
     @original_text = proofread
     @paragraphs = paragraphs
   end

end

module Parser

    def parse(file:file)
      @file = Zip::File.open(file) 
    end

    def remove_bookmarks
      @file.at("//w:bookmarkStart").remove if @file.at("//w:bookmarkStart")
      @file.at("//w:bookmarkEnd").remove if @file.at("//w:bookmarkEnd")
    end

    ...

end
```

You could also do something like:

```
module Parser

    attr_reader :file

    def parse(file:file)
      @file = Zip::File.open(file) 
    end

    def remove_bookmarks
      file.at("//w:bookmarkStart").remove if file.at("//w:bookmarkStart")
      file.at("//w:bookmarkEnd").remove if file.at("//w:bookmarkEnd")
    end

    ...

end
```

If you are using a recent version of Ruby you can probably also change `file.at("//w:bookmarkStart").remove if file.at("//w:bookmarkStart")`
to the simpler
`file.at("//w:bookmarkStart")&.remove`

Comment: Thank you Marc for the file.at("//w:bookmarkStart")&.remove and your answer. I'm using Ruby version 2.2.3. When I tried the code it gave me an error "unexpected '.'". Do I need ruby version 2.4?

Comment: It was introduced in Ruby 2.3, it's called the safe-navigation operator. If performance is an issue I would consider saving the return value of the `at` function (which looks slow).

Comment: Thanks Marc. I will save the return value of the at function, great idea and bump up to Ruby 2.3 to take advantage of the new syntax.